# Is it possible for someone else to add a photo to text messages I am sending?

Tags: mobile, spyware

Is it possible for someone else to intercept a text message I am sending and add a photo to that message?  I recently answered a text message I received from a friend and half way through typing out the reply, an old intimate photograph of me inserted itself into the body of the text message.  Can this be done by someone else i.e. an ex who may have someone put spyware on my phone and whilst monitoring my text messages has decided to add this photo? Is there anything out there that is capable of this?

Comment: What application were you using? What kind of phone? Had you viewed the image recently? Are you sure that the photo came from you and not the receiving party?

Answer (score 2):

That would require the connection or receiving app to be compromised, the former an unlikely premise for a modern app using AES, like [Google Hangouts](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/6046115?hl=en%20%22Google%20Hangouts) or [Telegram](https://telegram.org/faq#q-so-how-do-you-encrypt-data) and I don't believe that rootless apps can manipulate other app content.

**In short**, yes, it is possible, but if you use a modern, **secure** app (and don't let your ex use your phone), it can only be from a selfrooted spyware app.

**EDIT (questions from comments, until i can comment):**
@Steve SMS does not support photos. MMS is a viable attack vector, as it is not often encrypted. As such, migration to an AES encrypted message app is recommended.

@Neil App verification can be completed through secure hash and comparison with a known good copy.

Comment: And what about SMS/MMS? Is that authenticated and sent over end-to-end encrypted and integrity-protected channels?

Comment: Once you've let others have access to your phone, how can you be sure you're running the official messaging app? I don't think you need selfrooted spyware to install a lookalike, malicious app.

Comment: Review the certificates installed on the phone.

Comment: App verification is done be default. All apps are signed by their developers, and your phone verifies the identity of the app on install.

Comment: FYI, telegram isn't all that secure. http://www.alexrad.me/discourse/a-264-attack-on-telegram-and-why-a-super-villain-doesnt-need-it-to-read-your-telegram-chats.html